# Map Form field to contact details

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have gone through the doc.
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-submit-action-that-updates-contact-details.html

In the section "Add a folder that contains parameters for the editor" There is a table with column headers; FormDropList, Parameter, ValueFieldName, DisplayFieldName, FormLabel, BindingConfiguration I wanted to know what should be the value of the columns.

Comment: Pankaj Thakur, Chris auer

Comment: May I know your ultimate goal/requirement? whether you want the mapping feature or just storing the Sitecore Forms field values to contact would be enough?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the doc, you should be entering the values as such you see in the table.

In that section you will need to create three items of **FormDropList Parameters** Template. For each item you will find the fields like ValueFieldName, DisplayFieldName, FormLabel, BindingConfiguration and in these fields you will fill the values as listed in the table without any modification.

For example, First you should create the item **FirstName** which is of "FormDropList Parameters" Template. Then in this item, fill up the field **ValueFieldName** with the value "itemId", then **DisplayFieldName** field with the value "name", **FormLabel** field with the value "First name" and BindingConfiguration field with the value(Key-value pair) "firstNameFieldId/SelectedValue".

You can also refer the screenshot attached
[image]

And repeat the same step for the items **LastName** and **Email**.